# html arrange div inside the table

Tags: html, css

I need a little hand. So basically im trying to arrange the div inside the table but for some reason I could not. I already tried adding tr, td but it keeps messing the code now im here for some assistance.

Here is a sample picture of what I did. 
Sample Picture

[image]

As you can see timer goes first before the Title or the names. So I want to change their position. I want to the title to appear first before the timer.

Now Here is the sample picture of what I wanted

[image]

Here below is the code for the firt picture sample.

```html
<table width="214" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 10px; ">
<tr>
<td height="48" style="background-image:url(template/<?=$core['config']['template'] ?>/images/eventsmenu.png) "><div class="m_title"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-image:url(template/<?=$core['config']['template'] ?>/images/bg_snbmid.png); background-repeat:repeat-y; "><ul class="snb_1dep">

<table width="95%" height="119" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="gen_table">
<tr>
<td height="69" align="center" valign="top" class="n_back">
<table width="200" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">

        <div id="events"> 
          <script type="text/javascript" src="template/<?=$core['config']['template'] ?>/js/time.js"></script> 
          <script type="text/javascript">MuEvents.init('00:00:00');</script> 
 </div>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="n_foot">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the css if you want to see.

```css
/* Styles */

#left_box_body {
width: 220px;
margin-left: 80px;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-bottom: -90px;
}



#events dt {
  padding: 1px 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

#events span {
  display:block;
  font-size:11px;
}

#events {
  margin:5px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.rightfloat { float: right; }

/*
  MUCore CSS Start
*/
```

If you are looking for the timer code here is it below.

```html
var MuEvents = {};
MuEvents.text = [
        [lang[0], lang[1]],
        [lang[2], lang[3]]
];

MuEvents.sked = [
  ['Blood Castle',        0,      '02:30', '04:30', '06:30', '08:30', '10:30', '12:30', '14:30', '16:30', '18:30', '20:30', '22:30', '22:30'],
  ['Chaos Castle',        0,      '02:40', '04:40', '06:40', '08:40', '10:40', '12:40', '14:40', '16:40', '18:40', '20:40', '22:40', '22:40'],
  ['Devil Square',        0,      '01:00', '03:00', '05:00', '07:00', '09:00', '11:00', '13:00', '15:00', '17:00', '19:00', '21:00', '23:00'],
  ['Illusion Temple',     0,      '01:20', '05:20', '09:20', '13:20', '17:20', '20:20', '21:20', '23:20'],
  ['Happy Hour',        0,      '12:00'],
  ['BlueEvent',        0,      '10:35', '12:05', '13:25', '15:07', '18:25'],
  ['White Wizard',        1,      '13:00', '19:00'],
  ['Golden Invasion',     1,      '23:23', '18:25', '00:00', '06:00', '20:00', '14:05'],
  ['Red Dragon Invasion', 1,      '14:00', '20:00'],
  ['Loren Deep',          0,    '20:00']
];

MuEvents.init = function (e) {

        if (typeof e == "string") 
        var g = new Date(new Date().toString().replace(/\date('H')+:\date('i')+:\date('s')+/g, e));
        var f = (typeof e == "number" ? e : (g.getHours() * 60 + g.getMinutes()) * 60 + g.getSeconds()), q = MuEvents.sked, j = [];       
        
        for (var a = 0; a < q.length; a++) {
                var n = q[a];
                for (var k = 2; k < q[a].length; k++) {
                        var b = 0, p = q[a][k].split(":"), o = (p[0] * 60 + p[1] * 1) * 60, c = q[a][2].split(":");
                        if (q[a].length - 1 == k && (o - f) < 0) b = 1;
                        var r = b ? (1440 * 60 - f) + ((c[0] * 60 + c[1] * 1) * 60) : o - f;
                        if (f <= o || b) {
                                var l = Math.floor((r / 60) / 60), l = l < 10 ? "0" + l : l, d = Math.floor((r / 60) % 60), d = d < 10 ? "0" + d : d, u = r % 60, u = u < 10 ? "0" + u : u;
                                j.push('<dt class="event">' + (l == 0 && !q[a][1] && d < 5 ? '<img src="template/default/images/online.png" />' : '') + '<b class="rightfloat">' + q[a][b ? 2 : k] + "</b><b>" + n[0] + '</b><span><div class="rightfloat">' + (l + ":" + d + ":" + u) + "</div>" + (MuEvents.text[q[a][1]][+(l == 0 && d < (q[a][1] ? 1 : 5))]) + "</span>");
                                break;
                        };
                };
        };
        document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = j.join("");
        setTimeout(function () {
                MuEvents.init(f == 86400 ? 1 : ++f);
        }, 1000);
};
```

Im no so sure but im thinking the problem is somewhere here?

```html
<table width="200" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">

        <div id="events"> 
          <script type="text/javascript" src="template/<?=$core['config']['template'] ?>/js/time.js"></script> 
          <script type="text/javascript">MuEvents.init('00:00:00');</script> 
 </div>

</table>
```

EDIT HTML

```html
<div id="events"><dt class="event"><b class="rightfloat">02:30</b><b>Blood Castle</b><span><div class="rightfloat">03:22:35</div>Starts at</span></dt><dt class="event"><b class="rightfloat">02:40</b><b>Chaos Castle</b><span><div class="rightfloat">03:32:35</div>Starts at</span></dt>
  <dt
  class="event"><b class="rightfloat">01:00</b><b>Devil Square</b><span><div class="rightfloat">01:52:35</div>Starts at</span>
    </dt><dt class="event"><b class="rightfloat">23:20</b><b>Illusion Temple</b><span><div class="rightfloat">00:12:35</div>Starts at</span></dt><dt class="event"><b class="rightfloat">12:00</b><b>Happy Hour</b><span><div class="rightfloat">12:52:35</div>Starts at</span></dt>
    <dt
    class="event"><b class="rightfloat">10:35</b><b>BlueEvent</b><span><div class="rightfloat">11:27:35</div>Starts at</span>
      </dt><dt class="event"><b class="rightfloat">13:00</b><b>White Wizard</b><span><div class="rightfloat">13:52:35</div>Starts at</span></dt><dt class="event"><b class="rightfloat">23:23</b><b>Golden Invasion</b><span><div class="rightfloat">00:15:35</div>Starts at</span></dt>
      <dt
      class="event"><b class="rightfloat">14:00</b><b>Red Dragon Invasion</b><span><div class="rightfloat">14:52:35</div>Starts at</span>
        </dt><dt class="event"><b class="rightfloat">20:00</b><b>Loren Deep</b><span><div class="rightfloat">20:52:35</div>Starts at</span></dt>
</div>
```

Comment: What MuEvents.init('00:00:00'); prints? Could you inspect your HTML and post here what is inside the "events" div? It will be easier to understand the problem reason.

Comment: hello thank you for the response. If you want to see what is inside the "events" I posted it inside the css code (2nd quote)

Comment: Actually, I'd like to see the HTML that MuEvents.init('00:00:00'); is printing, not the CSS. In order to get it, you can inspect this item by your browser and copy the HTML code.

Comment: Not that snippets have three sections: one for HTML, one for JS, one for CSS. That way we can see what they all look like in one snippet. Right now, running the CSS snippet, say, shows nothing, since there is no HTML for it to act on. Also, your HTML is invalid; a `<table>` cannot be a child of a `<ul>`; only `<li>` can be a child of `<ul>`...

Comment: Hello please check my edited post at the bottom. I use Edit HTLM. If you want to see more please check my website www.staynightmu.com and scroll it down to see the timer @RodrigoLeite

Comment: thank you for the reply.. I removed the ul and class but nothing has change. Hold on I will try more solutions. @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: You're css class rightfloat is in css file twice, in the style.css file that is in the css file on line 58 it is set to float left, and in your other style.css file inside your template file on line 47 it is set to float right. The float left is running because it is called before the first one. If you remove the float-left from one style.css file and set your #events dt to text-align:left you get the result you want. Just need to play with the padding a bit.

Comment: Holy cow! I dont know how you get the line 58, because I keep seeing line 47. Yes! now I just tried to play with the padding and its all perfect now. You are amazing! thank you so much! @Benneb10